# Wrapping React components into div messing them up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I have my game like this:
[image: game]

Im using `react-contexify` to make a custom contextmenu in React
Here's my code before:

```
<MenuProvider key="0">
  <Message
    className="ChatMessage"
    style={{ width: isMobile() ? "60%" : "40%", backgroundColor: "#424751" }}
  >
    <h3 className="Username">{this.props.username}</h3>
    :&nbsp;
    <p className={Boolean(this.props.rainbow) ? "RainbowMessage" : "Message"}>
      {this.props.children}
    </p>
  </Message>

  <Menu>
    <Item>Lorem</Item>
    <Item>Ipsum</Item>
    <Separator />
    <Item disabled>Dolor</Item>
    <Separator />
    <Submenu label="Foobar">
      <Item>Foo</Item>
      <Item>Bar</Item>
    </Submenu>
  </Menu>
</MenuProvider>
```

And my code after:

```
<MenuProvider key="0">
                        <Message className="ChatMessage" style={{"width": isMobile() ? "60%" : "40%","backgroundColor": "#424751"}}>
                            <h3 className="Username">
                                {this.props.username}
                            </h3>
                            :&nbsp;
                            <p className={Boolean(this.props.rainbow) ? "RainbowMessage" : "Message"}>
                                {this.props.children}
                            </p>
                        </Message>

                        <Menu>
                            <Item>Lorem</Item>
                            <Item>Ipsum</Item>
                            <Separator />
                            <Item disabled>Dolor</Item>
                            <Separator />
                            <Submenu label="Foobar">
                            <Item>Foo</Item>
                            <Item>Bar</Item>
                            </Submenu>
                        </Menu>
                    </MenuProvider>
```

But this code results to this:
[image: mygameafter]

It's the same as having wrapped it in a div...
But why? What's wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's causing the issue, but I'm pretty sure the only actual difference between your two code examples, aside from formatting, is that the second one has `"width"` and `"backgroundColor"` wrapped in quotation marks.

Comment: Nope, that isn't the issue :/

Comment: there must be a difference somewhere else in your code then

Comment: theres none, with the devtools i checked div thats wrapping all the react components, its class is `react-contextmenu-wrapper`, and when i delete it, everything's back to normal... what can i do?

Comment: maybe theres some conflict between the styles applied by `react-contextmenu-wrapper` and your `ChatMessage` class. Have you tried removing your styles to see what the library is doing by itself?

Comment: It's adding some styles like:

Comment: ```css
    width: 40%;
    background-color: rgb(66, 71, 81);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
```
but when i remove them, its not doing anything

Comment: I just tried with a <div> without any style and it does the same thing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191405/discussion-between-demo-and-jsonaleo).